# Delphi Indy ReadLn with timeout

Tags: delphi, indy

An Indy question.

I added a timeout parameter to my `TIdTCPClient` `ReadLn` call so my thread could check for terminated every so often.  However, if the timeout happens, I never get any data from the `ReadLn` from that point on.  How do I reset the `TIdTCPClient` so it will look for a line again?

```
procedure TClientListner.Execute;
var
  msg : String;

begin

  while not terminated do
  begin
    msg := fSocketCon.IOHandler.ReadLn('\n', 200);
    if not fSocketCon.IOHandler.ReadLnTimedOut then
    begin
      DoSomeThing(msg);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unlike in C/C++, `\` is not an escape character, so `'\n'` is not interpreted as a line feed in Delphi.  It is a actual 2-character string, a `'\'` character followed by a `'n'` character.

To use a real line feed as the terminator, use `#10` or Indy's `LF` constant instead:

```
msg := fSocketCon.IOHandler.ReadLn(#10, 200);
```

```
msg := fSocketCon.IOHandler.ReadLn(LF, 200);
```

Or, use a blank string, which tells `ReadLn()` to use its default `LF` terminator:

```
msg := fSocketCon.IOHandler.ReadLn('', 200);
```

Or, don't use the `ATimeout` parameter at all.  Use the `ReadTimeout` property instead, and then don't specify a terminator so the default `LF` terminator is used:

```
fSocketCon.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 200;
...
msg := fSocketCon.IOHandler.ReadLn;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a dumb one, I was copying the \n from my Python side.